# Reduce gstreamer pipeline latency

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I'm converting an RTSP stream to HLS but I get about 30s of delay. Can someone help me reducing it?

Thanks in advice. This is the pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.27:554/ch0_0.265 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink location=/somewhere/segment_%05d.ts playlist-location=/somewhere/playlist.m3u8 target-duration=5 max-files=5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This latency is unavoidable here (HLS  is not designed for low latency streaming), you are creating .ts video files, 5 seconds long.
By default most HLS players will buffer 3 .ts files before playback continues.
This means you have at the very least 15 seconds latency.

If you bring your target duration down to 1 second. You might be able to get a latency of about 3 to 6 seconds. This might add more computational overhead.